# What type of ML is this? Algorithm to repeatedly choose 1 correct candidate from a pool (or none)

Tags: machine-learning, classification, regression

I have a set of 3-5 black box scoring functions that assign positive real value scores to candidates.

Each is decent at ranking the best candidate highest, but they don't always agree--I'd like to find how to combine the scores together for an optimal meta-score such that, among a pool of candidates, the one with the highest meta-score is usually the actual *correct* candidate.

So they are plain `R^n` vectors, but each dimension individually tends to have higher value for correct candidates.  Naively I could just multiply the components, but I hope there's something more subtle to benefit from.

If the highest score is too low (or perhaps the two highest are too close), I just give up and say 'none'.

So for each trial, my input is a set of these score-vectors, and the output is which vector corresponds to the actual right answer, or 'none'. This is kind of like tech interviewing where a pool of candidates are interviewed by a few people who might have differing opinions but in general each *tend* to prefer the best candidate.  My own application has an objective best candidate.

I'd like to maximize correct answers and minimize false positives.

More concretely, my training data might look like many instances of

{[0.2, 0.45, 1.37], [5.9, 0.02, 2], ...}  ->  i

where i is the ith candidate vector in the input set.

So I'd like to learn a function that tends to maximize the actual best candidate's score vector from the input.  There are no degrees of bestness.  It's binary right or wrong.  However, it doesn't seem like traditional binary classification because among an input set of vectors, there can be at most 1 "classified" as right, the rest are wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem doesn't exactly belong in the machine learning category. The multiplication method might work better. You can also try different statistical models for your output function.

ML, and more specifically classification, problems need training data from which your network can learn any existing patterns in the data and use them to assign a particular class to an input vector.

If you really want to use classification then I think your problem can fit into the category of **OnevsAll classification**. You will need a network (or just a single output layer) with number of cells/sigmoid units equal to your number of candidates (each representing one). Note, here your number of candidates will be fixed.

You can use your entire candidate vector as input to all the cells of your network. The output can be specified using one-hot encoding i.e. 00100 if your candidate no. 3 was the actual correct candidate and in case of no correct candidate output will be 00000.

For this to work, you will need a big data set containing your candidate vectors and corresponding actual correct candidate. For this data you will either need a function (again like multiplication) or you can assign the outputs yourself, in which case the system will learn how you classify the output given different inputs and will classify new data in the same way as you did. This way, it will maximize the number of correct outputs but the definition of correct here will be how you classify the training data.

You can also use a different type of output where each cell of output layer corresponds to your scoring functions and 00001 means that the candidate your 5th scoring function selected was the right one. This way your candidates will not have to be fixed. But again, you will have to manually set the outputs of the training data for your network to learn it.

**OnevsAll** is a classification technique where there are multiple cells in the output layer and each perform binary classification in between one of the classes vs all others. At the end the sigmoid with the highest probability is assigned 1 and rest zero.

Once your system has learned how you classify data through your training data, you can feed your new data in and it will give you output in the same way i.e. 01000 etc.

I hope my answer was able to help you.:)